# Autodesk Forge Viewer Exporter

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to get access to the manifest.json and metadata.json for a converted revit file that has children f2d.

If I convert a revit file. I get a manifest file that has a svf and f2d files

I know that I can open the svf file as a zip and get its manifest and metadata files to pull down all the files that go along with it.

but the f2d files are not zip files in a format that I understand. So my question is what is the f2d format and how can I access its manifest and metadata so that I can use it in the Viewer.
EXAMPLE:

```
{
          "role": "graphics",
          "mime": "application/autodesk-f2d",
          "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z3JlZ2JpbWJ1Y2tldHR3ZW50eXNpeC9SZXZpdF9TYW1wbGVfMjAxNi5ydnQ/output/332d9c2c-1bfd-51c1-35c6-aff868a7e5db_f2d/primaryGraphics.f2d",
          "status": "success",
          "type": "resource"
        },
```

Note 1 this is not a question about how to convert a DWG file directly. Its a question about converting a revit file that has 2D drawings.

Note 2 I am using the version v2 of the API to convert and pull down the converted files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something that got suggested to me by one of our engineer's was the following:

*The manifest.json.gz and metadata.json.gz are just files in the same location as the f2d file. But if you are using an F2D file in the viewer, why not use the viewer to load it, and then access those using model.getData().metadata and model.getData().manifest.*

I haven't tried it on my side, since I don't have anything setup to get the f2d files at the moment, but I thought it was worth the shot to try with you first.
I see from past questions you have been trying to understand the origin of the .sb and bin files you get back, have you been able to do so?

Comment: Thanks to your help I was able to get the manifest.json.gz and the metadata.json.gz.  Now I need to figure out a way to get all of the other json files that go with the f2d.  Manifest just shows the extra pngs that go with the f2d but not where to get the "objects_attrs.json.gz, objects_avs.json.gz , etc ..."

Comment: Also I have not been able to find the .sb files but I dont think version v2 uses them so I am not to worried about that

Comment: Hi Greg, just checking if your original question got answered with what I previously post. Feel free to raise any other new questions in a separate one.thanks.